# put some logical thinking into math :)

Tags: math, statistics, artificial-intelligence

lets say I have a list of items (a,b,c,d, ..)
and two counts. one "+", that the item was  right. one "-" that the item was wrong. 
example:

```
item | +   | -
a    | 150 | 100
b    | 50  | 0
c    | 1   | 0
d    | 0   | 50
```

What math do I need to do to get a number or percentage that shows the value of these items..
by value I mean:

B is very valuable to me.. its 100% correct and it happens a lot of times

C is also 100% correct ... but it only happened once.. so no real value ...

A happens a lot and is more correct than wrong... but not as valuable for me as B... (still more than C)

D is at the other spectrum of what I want to have (which is interesting as well!)

I would like to see my own logical thinking into a mathematical number. 
Is that possible?

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean by 'items'. Categories? Or tasks which were solved correct or incorrectly? In line with this, it would also be beneficial to be a bit more concrete regarding your underlying raw data. It seems to me that your question is a methodological one for which a specific statistical test might be appropriate. However, in order to propose a solution to your problem, more information needs to be provided.

Comment: Can't you just take the normal percentage? I.e.`correct/(correct+incorrect)`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: The normal percentage would leave me with B equaly important as C. Both answers would be "1". While B is clearly more important than C.
It is a problem I have with a PHP programming project. I got the question down to the basic logic :). what is programming but mostly math ..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precise the langage you want to use, but here it is:

```
Correctness = item.right / (item.right + item.wrong) * 100

Valuability = item.right + item.wrong
```

Multiply them together to obtain some kind of "global valuability"

Comment: need to leave work now. but checking asap.
although "Global valuability" is what could describe what I need :D.
PHP, but I'm really happy with pseudocode and logic

Comment: Glad it helped, but next time, precise the langage you'll be using or your question might be closed as "off-topic"